# View helper to remove inserting class object in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have a page in my rails app where I'm iterating over a collection of categories and adding a link to them. The link will go a category page

```
   <%@categories.each_with_index do |category, index|%>
    <div class="category-result">
        <div class="category-title"><%= link_to category["name"], 
        admin_question_path(index: 
       Question.first_category_question(category))%></div>
    ...
```

I've defined the method below

```
def self.first_category_question(category)
  Question.get_all_questions_by_category(category["name"])
          .first.question_index
end
```

Is there a way in rails to move 
 Question.first_category_question(category) to a helper. I would normally save this to a instance variable like @first_category_question in the controller and serve that in the view but I have an argument (category).

Comment: Can you update the post with `first_category_question` method?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an N+1 problem by doing it this way. Avoid it by preparing the data in advance in the controller just like you said. Pre make the needed query in the controller to do it with one call to the DB, then build an array of hashes and use that hash to build your links in the view without making any more additional calls to the DB.

You would have an array of hashes with something like:

```
@categories_and_questions = [{ name: 'category1', index: 1 }, { name: 'category2', index: 3 }]

@categories_and_questions.each do |cat|
  <div class="category-result">
    <div class="category-title"><%= link_to cat[:name], 
    admin_question_path(index: cat[:index])%></div></div>
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create a relation between categories and questions?

For example, if a category `has_many :questions` you'd be able to do category.questions to return all the questions you need.

To avoid N+1 you could then use `Category.includes(:questions).find_by(params)` in the controller to pull them all in with one database query.

Let me know if you want me to explain more.